# Mandatory Settings Update

Tags: android, settings

I am making one android app where one setting is must every user need to update that which is pincode.

So after successful login, if the user has not updated pincode yet, it needs to be updated mandatory before navigating to any other screen.

What is the best way to implement this? Any Ideas?

Update:

After answer, I meant to say that setting I will be fetching from firebase database as boolean flag. So my actual query is how to show that as a mandatory to get the user update? (i.e) either navigating to different activity or showing popup and getting the setting etc. I need UI design ideas.

What is the best practice?

Comment: check pincode box empty or not whats the big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is the point of this, and if you have a server side that controls that stuff, but I'll try to give a help.

If you have a Server controlling authentication:

- On login, call the API of your service to check if has happened or not. You could save the answer in a "shared preference" ([Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)), so you don't call your API every time.

If you only want to have the application on a client side:

- Use [1](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to store values that indicate if the desired action was performed or not, which is verified right after the login.

EDIT:
If the action is mandatory, you could send the user to an activity to update the pin, this will happen until the action is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Client side approach:

You can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to persist a value, like a simple boolean, that will inform you if that the user already updated the pincode or not.

I would recommend you to perform the check in the `onResume()` of your Launcher Activity.

Putting it simple and explicit:

```
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "PrefFileName";
    public static final String PREF_IS_PIN_CODE_UPDATED = "PREF_IS_PIN_CODE_UPDATED";

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isPinCodeUpdated = prefs.getBoolean(PREF_IS_PIN_CODE_UPDATED, false);
        if (isPinCodeUpdated) {
            // You can proceed
        } else {
            // Force the user to update the pin code, by prompting for instance a dialog where he can change the pin with setCancelable(false)
        }
    }
```

After you know that your user already updated the pin code you just need to set the preference to true.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean(PREF_IS_PIN_CODE_UPDATED, true);
    editor.apply();
```

After this every time the user opens the app it will pass in the `onResume()` method and your `isPinCodeUpdated` var will be true and the app should proceed as usual.

From you question I am assuming that you didn't want a response in terms of UI but how could you have the information persisted.

Note: This implementation fails for multiple users in the same device. With few tweaks you can make it work for multiple users in the same device but in my opinion this verification should be done server side.